# Add custom views options

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to add some custom view options. I am not even sure if what I'm trying to do is possible.

Basically I want to put a custom option under the **Other** category.

It would look like:

*My custom options*: [disabled](http://show-custom-form.co)

When the user clicks on "disabled", it should show a custom form where the user can set some settings for that view.

I have looked into this, but couldn't find anything that would let me add custom options here.

[image]

Comment: What settings are you intending to add?

Comment: what options are you wanting the user to be allowed to select?

Comment: Hard to think of a Views option that isn't already there ;)

Comment: I am creating a new module. In simple terms, the option could just be a true/false value. The user will be able to enable/disable a feature that I am creating. I will create a post_execute() hook I think, to check if the value is true/false, and then act on that value.

Answer (score 1):

What you're actually looking to do is to implement a custom Views Display Extender plugin (https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_plugins/7.x-3.x).

It's not particularly trivial and I got most of my information from this wonderful tutorial here: [How to write a Views Plugin Display Extender (D7) by Bryan Ollendyke](https://drupal.psu.edu/blog/post/how-write-views-plugin-display-extender-d7)

Here's a basic outline:

-create a custom module (let's call it mymodule) and implement [hook_views_api()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_api/7.x-3.x).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_api().
 */
function mymodule_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule'),
  );
}
```

-Create a mymodule.views.inc file (remembering to add the file to your mymodule.info file) and implement [hook_views_plugins()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_plugins/7.x-3.x). It should look something like this:

```
/**
* Implements hook_views_plugins().
 */
function mymodule_views_plugins() {
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module');
  $plugins = array();

  $plugins['display_extender'] = array(
    'mymodule' => array(
      'title' => t('Some Setting'),
      'help' => t('A description of the setting.'),
      'path' => $path,
      'handler' => 'mymodule_views_plugin_display_extender',
    ),
  );

  return $plugins;
}
```

-Note the "handler" index in the above array. You'll need to implement that in a file called mymodule_views_plugin_display_extender.inc (again, remembering to add that in your mymodule.info file). The implementation should look something like this:

```
class mymodule_views_plugin_display_extender extends views_plugin_display_extender {
  /**
   * Provide a form to edit options for this plugin.
   */
  function options_definition_alter(&$options) {
    $options['my_setting'] = array(
      'default' => 0,
    );
  }

  /**
   * Provide a form to edit options for this plugin.
   */
  function options_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
      parent::options_form($form, $form_state);

      if ($form_state['section'] === 'mymodule') {
        $form['my_setting'] = array(
          '#type' => 'checkbox',
          '#title' => t('Some Setting'),
          '#description' => t('A sample checkbox.'),
          '#default_value' => $this->display->get_option('my_setting'),
        );
      }
  }

  /**
   * Handle any special handling on the validate form.
   */
  function options_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $this->display->set_option('my_setting', $form_state['values']['my_setting']);
  }

  /**
   * Provide the default summary for options in the views UI.
   *
   * This output is returned as an array.
   */
  function options_summary(&$categories, &$options) {
    $options['mymodule'] = array(
      'category' => 'other',
      'title' => t('Some Setting'),
      'value' => ($this->display->get_option('my_setting')) ? 'Yes' : 'No',
      'desc' => t('Set a setting.'),
    );
  }

}
```

After all that your mymodule.info file should look something like this:

```
name = My Module
description = Sample views display extender
core = 7.x
version = 7.x-1.0

dependencies[] = views

files[] = mymodule.views.inc
files[] = mymodule_views_plugin_display_extender.inc
```

If that all works out, you should see a setting show up under "Other" (you can change that using the 'category' in the options_summary implementation in mymodule_views_plugin_display_extender.inc.

After that, in your module, you can access the option from the view using something like:

```
$view->display_handler->get_option('my_setting');
```

For instance, if you were implementing `[hook_views_post_execute()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_execute/7.x-3.x).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_post_execute().
 */
function mymodule_views_post_execute(&$view) {
  $my_setting = $view->display_handler->get_option('my_setting');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The form ID of the view edit form is `views_ui_edit_form`

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_ui_edit_form')
  {
        $other = &$form['displays']['settings']['settings_content']['tab_content']['details']['columns']['third']['collapse']['other'];
        $other['custom']['#theme'] = 'views_ui_display_tab_setting';
        $other['custom']['#description'] = 'Custom';
        $other['custom']['#link'] = '<a href="' .  base_path() . '/node/1" title="Get information on how to theme this display" id="views-page-1-custom">Custom</a>';

  }

}
```

The form item for the OTHER section is

```
['displays']['settings']['settings_content']['tab_content']['details']['columns']['third']['collapse']['other']
```

so in the function this form element is taken into the `$other` variable as reference for ease of use.

This one simply adds a link to the node/1 you can edit it to do what you want. And the example does not take ajax into concern you can print out the $other variable to get an idea of what all details are given and how it all works.